# How to work with templates in magento 2

Tags: template, login, customer-account

Example.com/customer/account/login/

This page contains three Templates

1. Sociallogin.phtml
2. Login.phtml
3. Newcustomer.phtml

I know where these files are located.But i don't know where these files are combined and how these files are shown in a single page.I want to change position of social login buttons into login box.

[image: Login page image]

Answer (score 0):

**Seems its a custom theme. I am giving you an example of default magento2 installation.But you will get the whole idea.**
So first you need to check the `url in magento2`. Here the url is

> Example.com/customer/account/login/

So you need to `find the layout handler` name `customer_account_login.xml` file. Because unlike magento1 here every handler has its own .xml file.

Now because of the `sake of module structure` you can find it inside `Magento_Customer` module . File path would be this `Magento\Customer\view\frontend\layout`. Now when you will open the file you will see this below code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <!-- customer.form.login.extra -->
            <container name="customer.login.container" label="Customer Login Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="login-container">
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login" name="customer_form_login" template="Magento_Customer::form/login.phtml">
                    <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Form\Login\Info" name="customer.new" template="Magento_Customer::newcustomer.phtml"/>
            </container>
            <block class="Magento\Cookie\Block\RequireCookie" name="require-cookie" template="Magento_Cookie::require_cookie.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="triggers" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="loginButton" xsi:type="string">.action.login</item>
                    </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="form_additional_info_customer" template="Magento_Customer::additionalinfocustomer.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here you will find the 2 files which is showing in that page which are `login.phtml` and `newcustomer.phtml`. Both you can find inside the `customer.login.container`.